# jQuery DOM element creation

Tags: jquery

I'm creating some elements using this code:

```
var itemButton = $('<button />',{'id': 'searchItemButtonId'+p[i].Id, 'class': 'itemButton', 'onclick':'javascript:alert();'}).append('Add');
```

The item is created with correct id and class set but the 'onclick' part doesn't work. Any ideea what is the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery events drop the `on` prefix, plus you need to provide a function, not a string.

```
$("<button>", {
    click : function () {
        alert('something');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the jquery click method? So you don't need the onclick attribute

```
$('<button />',{'id': 'searchItemButtonId'+p[i].Id, 'class': 'itemButton'}).click( function(){ alert('asdf'); });
```

Comment: The example that happened to you "@Andy"works well, you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/hNdpp/

Comment: Then maybe it something with my code as only the nickf way works for me.